# Writing a script for finding the largest and second largest eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix.

Tags: matlab

For a final project in my linear algebra intro, I have been tasked with writing a script that finds the largest and the second largest eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix in Matlab.  For the best possible grade, it must include a function as well.  So far, I have been able to get my script to verify that a matrix is symmetric, and am feeling a little bit stuck.  I need some guidance for finishing this assignment, as my Matlab experience is extremely limited.

---

Here is what I have so far:

```
prompt = 'Please input a symmetric matrix A.'
A = input(prompt);
if (A == A'),
    eig(A)
else
    disp('A is not a symmetric matrix.  Please input a symmetric matrix.')
end
```

---

Note that the script hopefully verifies that `A` is symmetric, and I have the eigenvalues for `A`, but I am not sure where to go from here to $1$. find the eigenvectors, $2$. get the two largest eigenvectors, and $3$. write a useful function to fit into the script.  I would be very grateful for any help given.  Thanks!

Comment: This may be better suited for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab

Comment: I'll x-post it there.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, they'll probably know the specific syntax. If there's not a syntax for getting eigenvectors, you can look at the nullspace of $A - \lambda I$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. That'll give you the eigenvectors. The other two steps are just MATLAB syntax somehow.

Comment: To reinforce(?) @HenrySwanson 's Comment, if the Question is about an approach (Matlab: full eigensolution followed by picking out the two largest eigenvalues) already decided upon, it would certainly be ripe for SO.  A mathematical (but computational) question would be how to best approximate the two top eigenvalues *without* getting all of them (such questions are also handled at SciComp.SE).

Comment: It's the $\large\tt Power\ Method$ algorithm or $\large\tt Von\ Mises$ one which yields the eigenvalue of largest magnitude. Once you get this, you can "remove" that eigenvalue and repeat the algorithm for the next one. See ---> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration

Comment: Another options is to use the [eigs](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) command, which returns a subset of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Given the $n$-iterated vector $\Psi_{n}$, we get the net one $\Psi_{n + 1}$ with
$$
\Psi_{n + 1} = {\varphi_{n} \over \lambda_{n}}\,,\quad
\mbox{where}\quad \varphi_{n} \equiv A\Psi_{n}
$$
$\lambda_{n}$ is the component of $\varphi_{n}$ with the largest magnitude. After $N$ ( "many" ) iterations, we get the eigenvalue as $\lambda_{N}$. This is the eigenvalue with the largest magnitude. Next, we normalize the eigenvector:
$\ds{\varphi_{N} \to {\varphi_{N} \over \varphi_{N}^{\sf T}\,\varphi_{N}}}$. "Reduce" the matrix as
$$
\tilde{A} \equiv A - \lambda_{N}\ \varphi_{N}\varphi_{N}^{\sf T}
$$
Repeat the procedure with $\tilde{A}$ and so on.

See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).